# Which Visual Studio Command Window commands to you find most useful?

Tags: visual-studio, command-window

I've only recently started using the Visual Studio Command Window, and for the vast majority of the time, it's in order to use the of (open file) command. Which commands do you find the most useful (and what do they do, if it's not obvious)?

Comment: This is a good question, but it should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`of` - open file. Its autocomplete feature makes it invaluable in solutions with many files.